# Secure json WEBAPI connection on chat application for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a chat application for the Windows Phone 8. I'm facing a problem but don't know whats the best solution. this is my problem:
I'm using a `webapi` for my chat. So everyone can send requests to it from the browser. Now I need to check if the sender of the message is the real user, But I have no idea how to check this. Also the connection has to be secure, but I don't have the money for a certificate. Is there a other option to do this?

I am new to this so its hard for me to explain what I really want. I hope you guys understood and can help me out.

Comment: You'll need to look into authorization strategies for the WebAPI. What have you tried? Also, there are free or very cheap SSL certificates available around the web if you look.